# perl regex ignore specific keywords

Tags: regex, linux, perl

I have following output:

```
22.0 MiB +  27.1 MiB =  49.2 MiB       process1
78.9 MiB + 636.5 KiB =  79.5 MiB       process2
```

I need last to column so i am using following regex, I am putting (XX MiB values and processX in two group $1 and $2)

```
/([^=]+)\s([a-z].*)/
```

Result:

```
49.2 MiB
79.5 MiB
```

I want to ignore/remove `MiB` in regex group how do i remove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use,

```
=\s*(\d+\.\d+)\s*\w+\s*(\w+)
```

[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/lE4lM5/1)

Comment: More robust: `=\s*(\S+)\s+\S+\s+(.*)`

Answer (score 0):

Just don't capture what you don't want to keep:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    /= \s* ([0-9.]+) \s MiB/x and print $1, "\n";
}

__DATA__
22.0 MiB +  27.1 MiB =  49.2 MiB       process1
78.9 MiB + 636.5 KiB =  79.5 MiB       process2
```

Comment: @apgp88 and you hit answer same time, you both great but i going to answer `apgp88` it directly hit the solution:

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if ( $_ =~  /(=\s+)(.*[\d\.]+)/ ) {
      print "$2\n";
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 m{ = ([0-9]+ (?: [.][0-9]+)? ) \s+ \S+ \s+ (\S+) }x
```